# ¿Cómo dar permisos de administrador a Apache en Linux?

Tags: linux, apache, permisos

Estoy en *Linux* y quisiera que *Apache* de *Lampp* (o *Xampp*) tenga permisos de administrador, es decir, ser como *root*.

El usuario es `daemon`, pero quiero que inicie como `root`.

El motivo de esto es que quiero iniciar el solitario de `flatpak` desde el navegador, mediante el `exec` de *PHP*, y cuando lo hago me da error de permiso denegado.

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

Comment: Cambia lo demás para que no necesite root. Si hay una vulnerabilidad en Apache o en lo que corres sobre apache, vas a exponer TODO el servidor. Mala idea, mala práctica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Importante:** No es buena idea ejecutar Apache (o cualquier otra aplicación) como `root`, incluso, puede que la misma aplicación te impida ejecutarla de esa forma.

Solo necesitas editar el archivo de configuración de Apache y buscar el siguiente bloque:

```
<IfModule unixd_module>
#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User www-data
Group www-data

</IfModule>
```

Actualiza usuario y grupo bajo el que deseas que se ejecute Apache, puede ser tu mismo usuario, quizá con eso evites tener que hacerlo con `root`.

Desconozco XAMPP, pero puedes usar su herramienta de configuración para acceder al archivo, o buscarlo en `/opt/lamp/etc/httpd.conf`

Guarda el archivo y reinicia el servicio.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora solo me falta recompilar Apache.

Comment: @ArtEze, no es necesario recompilar, solo reiniciar el servicio y lo puedes hacer desde el panel de XAMPP.

Comment: Es que me aparece esto... "add -DBIG_SECURITY_HOLE to the CFLAGS env variable and then rebuild the server."... No pude compilarlo por un problema de mi compilador. Al final me hice un servidor en NodeJS.